# HTML 5 and IE conditional statements in Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm publishing my site with Adobe Business Catalyst.
The following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>       <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>          <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->  <html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

after publishing it becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

Most probably BC doesn't accept anything before the  element.
Is there an alternative (code or place)?

Answer (score 0):

> Most probably BC doesn't accept anything before the element.

No, more likely because it is stripping out comments, and the `<!-- -->` conditionals are seen as comments (they're actually called "conditional comments").

BC may have a config option to strip out comments. If it does, switching that config option off should solve the problem. (it will also leave other comments in your code though, which you may or may not want)

Alternatively, you could re-think how you deal with browser compatibility. Detecting the browser version is often not the right approach anyway. You might want to consider using a Javascript library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which will help you detect support for specific features in the user's browser, rather than just detecting the browser itself.

This would probably allow you to ditch all those variations of your `<html>` tag entirely, and just use a single standard one regardless of the browser version.